# How to switch widgets in stacked widget using a button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

So I have created a stacked widget with 2 pages. In the first page, I have one button " Sign In ". In the second page, I have One button " Logout"

I want that, if I click on the "Sign in" button it will open another page/widget with the " Logout " button in the stacked widget.

First Page Index = 0
Second page index = 1

Sign in button object name = pushButton
Logout button object name = LogoutBtn

this is my code from PyQt5 :

```
class Ui_StackedWidget(object):


def setupUi(self, StackedWidget):
    StackedWidget.setObjectName("StackedWidget")
    StackedWidget.resize(470, 406)
    self.page1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.page1.setObjectName("page1")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page1)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 170, 35, 10))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page1)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 200, 35, 10))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page1)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 230, 56, 17))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.page1)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 170, 113, 16))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.page1)
    self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 200, 113, 16))
    self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page1)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 120, 35, 10))
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    StackedWidget.addWidget(self.page1)
    self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.page.setObjectName("page")
    self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page)
    self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 70, 101, 16))
    self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
    self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page)
    self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 110, 91, 16))
    self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
    self.CreateBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page)
    self.CreateBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 160, 56, 17))
    self.CreateBtn.setObjectName("CreateBtn")
    self.ShowBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page)
    self.ShowBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 190, 56, 17))
    self.ShowBtn.setObjectName("ShowBtn")
    self.DeleteBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page)
    self.DeleteBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 220, 56, 17))
    self.DeleteBtn.setObjectName("DeleteBtn")
    self.UpdateBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page)
    self.UpdateBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 250, 56, 17))
    self.UpdateBtn.setObjectName("UpdateBtn")
    self.LogoutBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page)
    self.LogoutBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 320, 56, 17))
    self.LogoutBtn.setObjectName("LogoutBtn")
    StackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
    self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
    self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_2)
    self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 90, 141, 16))
    self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
    self.Logout1Btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page_2)
    self.Logout1Btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 320, 56, 17))
    self.Logout1Btn.setObjectName("Logout1Btn")
    self.main1Btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page_2)
    self.main1Btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 320, 56, 17))
    self.main1Btn.setObjectName("main1Btn")
    self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_2)
    self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 180, 35, 10))
    self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
    StackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)



    self.retranslateUi(StackedWidget)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(StackedWidget)
```

then I created a function switching ( i saw a reference in StackOverflow ) _

```
def switching(self):
    self.ui = Ui_StackedWidget()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    self.ui.LogoutBtn.clicked.connect(lambda : self.ui.StackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0))
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda : self.ui.StackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))
```

But it doesn't switch between windows.

Comment: show the class of switching

Answer (score 1):

According to the code you provide, I deduce that you used StackedWidget as a template, so the class you use fills in ui to inherit from that class.

An error that I see in your code is `self.ui.StackedWidget` since ui has no attribute called `StackedWidget`, so you should throw an exception.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_StackedWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, StackedWidget):
        # ...

    def retranslateUi(self, StackedWidget):
        # ...


class StackedWidget(QtWidgets.QStackedWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_StackedWidget()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.LogoutBtn.clicked.connect(lambda : self.setCurrentIndex(0))
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda : self.setCurrentIndex(1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = StackedWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, The widget switching worked. But my first widget is "Sign In page", where I put two line edits  "username" and "password", also one push button " Sign in" .. when i click on sign in button it takes me to another widget with a " Logout button"  , so when i click on Logout button , it take me to "Sign In page" but the problem is i can see the Username text and password text still there. what can i do to remove those ? actually  i want every widget refreshes when i leave that widget.

Comment: @IhsanAhmadSiddiquee provide a real [mre]

Comment: I want Every widgets to refresh when i leave that widget.